# R: replacing NAs in a data.frame with values in the same position in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a dataframe with some NA values:

```
dfa <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA,3,4,5,NA),b=c(1,5,NA,NA,8,9),c=c(7,NA,NA,NA,2,NA))
dfa
```

I would like to replace the NAs with values in the same position in another dataframe:

```
dfrepair <- data.frame(a=c(2:7),b=c(6:1),c=c(8:3))
dfrepair
```

I tried:

```
dfa1 <- dfa

dfa1 <- ifelse(dfa == NA, dfrepair, dfa)
dfa1
```

but this did not work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do:

```
dfa <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA,3,4,5,NA),b=c(1,5,NA,NA,8,9),c=c(7,NA,NA,NA,2,NA))
dfrepair <- data.frame(a=c(2:7),b=c(6:1),c=c(8:3))
dfa[is.na(dfa)] <- dfrepair[is.na(dfa)]
dfa

  a b c
1 1 1 7
2 3 5 7
3 3 4 6
4 4 3 5
5 5 8 2
6 7 9 3
```

Comment: If creating a new table instead of modifying dfa: `replace(dfa, is.na(dfa), dfrepair[is.na(dfa)])`

Comment: In case the `data.frame` has different types, this way might change the type of the columns. Try it with `dfrepair <- data.frame(a=letters[2:7],b=c(6:1),c=c(8:3))` what will change *all* columns of `dfa` from `numeric` to `character`.

Answer (score 8):

In the tidyverse, you can use `purrr::map2_df`, which is a strictly bivariate version of `mapply` that simplifies to a data.frame, and `dplyr::coalesce`, which replaces `NA` values in its first argument with the corresponding ones in the second.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfrepair %>% 
    mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%    # coalesce is strict about types
    map2_df(dfa, ., coalesce)

## # A tibble: 6 × 3
##       a     b     c
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     1     1     7
## 2     3     5     7
## 3     3     4     6
## 4     4     3     5
## 5     5     8     2
## 6     7     9     3
```

Answer (score 8):

We can use `Map` from `base R` to do a columnwise comparison between the two datasets

```
dfa[] <- Map(function(x,y) {x[is.na(x)] <- y[is.na(x)]; x}, dfa, dfrepair)
dfa
#  a b c
#1 1 1 7
#2 3 5 7
#3 3 4 6
#4 4 3 5
#5 5 8 2
#6 7 9 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dfa <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA,3,4,5,NA),b=c(1,5,NA,NA,8,9),c=c(7,NA,NA,NA,2,NA))
dfa
dfrepair <- data.frame(a=c(2:7),b=c(6:1),c=c(8:3))
dfrepair 
library(dplyr)
coalesce(as.numeric(dfa), as.numeric(dfrepair))

  a b c
1 1 1 7
2 3 5 7
3 3 4 6
4 4 3 5
5 5 8 2
6 7 9 3
```

As the code in `dplyr` is written in C++ it is faster in most cases. An other important advantage is that `coalesce` as well as many other `dplyr` functions are the same in SQL. Using `dplyr` you learn SQL by coding in `R`. ;-)

Comment: The `as.numeric`s error out for me, though `coalesce(dfa, dfrepair)` surprisingly _does_ work (the docs only talk about vectors, not whole data.frames) and doesn't complain about the different types.

Comment: Thank you for the as.numeric. ;-) A data.frame is a list of list and vectors. In the case above as well as in many other cases it is just a list of vectors containing numbers. Therefore in our case it is very similar to a matrix. If the data.frame contains recursive lists my code will not run.

Comment: A data.frame may look like a matrix, but the underlying structure is very different. A data.frame is a list of one-dimensional vectors, whereas a matrix is a single vector with two dimensions. Most functions designed for vectors don't work on data.frames; the subsetting in `coalesce` must be fortuitous.

Comment: `A <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
 is.vector(A)` renders `FALSE`. According to this test a matrix is not a single vector in R.

Comment: From [the language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Attributes): "Matrices and arrays are simply vectors with the attribute dim and optionally dimnames attached to the vector." E.g. `x <- diag(3); attributes(x) <- NULL; x` Lists are vectors too (generic, not atomic), e.g. `is.vector(list(1))`, making the word confusing. `is.vector` just checks for attributes other than names, which is why `is.vector(iris)` returns `FALSE` even though `typeof(iris)` returns `"list"`. A better check: `purrr::is_vector(diag(3)); purrr::is_atomic(diag(3))`: `TRUE`; `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

In case there are different types the replacement should be done columnwise. Another simple way allowing in place exchange might be.

```
for(i in seq_along(dfa)) {
    . <- is.na(dfa[[i]])
    dfa[[i]][.] <- dfrepair[[i]][.]
}
```

Or using in addition `which` which might improve speed / memory usage in some cases.

```
for(i in seq_along(dfa)) {
    . <- which(is.na(dfa[[i]]))
    dfa[[i]][.] <- dfrepair[[i]][.]
}
```

Benchmark of columnwise *base* options.

```
dfa <- data.frame(a=c("A",NA,"B","C","D",NA),b=c(1,5,NA,NA,8,9),c=c(7,NA,NA,NA,2,NA))
dfrepair <- data.frame(a=letters[2:7],b=c(6:1),c=c(8:3))

bench::mark(
akrun = local({dfa[] <- Map(function(x,y) {x[is.na(x)] <- y[is.na(x)]; x}, dfa, dfrepair); dfa}),
GKi = local({for(i in seq_along(dfa)) {. <- is.na(dfa[[i]])
                 dfa[[i]][.] <- dfrepair[[i]][.]}
                 dfa})
)
#  expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 akrun        64.4µs 70.3µs    12895.      280B     26.7  5793    12      449ms
#2 GKi          54.8µs   60µs    16347.      280B     28.7  7395    13      452ms
```